# i want to pprint from a c.execute in python and sql but i don't know how to

Tags: python, sql, printing

```
c.execute("SELECT 'Fistname','Lastname','Year','Form','Phone','Adress' FROM Students")
```

Comment: Go through Before posting a Query [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

From the [API documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html):

```
for row in c.execute("SELECT Fistname,Lastname,Year,Form,Phone,Adress FROM Students"):
    print row
```

Comment: Thanks ""feeling the blanks""""""